# Pretendo enviar dados do esp8266 para uma base dados no localhost

Tags: arduino

Boas, tenho este código que futuramente vai ler a temperatura e humidade através de sensores.
Mas agora estava testando se conseguia enviar os dados para a base de dados, algo que está a dar erro.
Eu consigo ligar-me ao wifi (hotspot do smartphone) mas não consigo conectar ao server. O que devo fazer?

**Código:**

```
#include < ESP8266WiFi.h >

const char* ssid = "ESP-8266";
const char* password = "esp8266imsi";
const char* server = "192.168.8.100";

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {   

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");


}
void loop() {

  Serial.print("Temperature: 25\n");
  if (client.connect(server,80)) { 
    String url = "/post-esp-data.php?humsolo=";
    url += ("25");
    url += ("&temp=");
    url += ("30");
    Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);

    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + server + "\r\n" +
                 "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Erro ao enviar!\n");
  }
  client.stop();

  Serial.println("Waiting...\n");   
  // delay between updates
  delay(30000);  //30s minute delay
}
```